# Sql query to show highest in different categories

Tags: php, sql

Hello i am trying to execute a query wherein i need the max weight of the fish according to the each line weight i.e if the line weight of a fish is 60 and weight caught is 100 and 200,it should show up only the 200 value and not the 100 value similarly this goes on for all other fishes in the table

The query is as shown in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80c6d/12

Here i need the table to be as follows:

```
Name  Weight  Line Weight
abc   200     60
abc   100     20
abc   100     10
pqr   300     60
pqr   100     20
```

I tried using unique in the query but it does not help as i need the same line weight again for the other names of fishes.I am implementing this on a php page,it would be helpful if a get a query or any functions of php .Please help

Comment: You could make use from one the aggregate functions http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-aggregate-functions.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic group by clause might help in this situation:

```
select
  fish_name, 
  line_weight,
  max(fish_weight) max_fish_weight
from
  <your table name>
group by
  fish_name,
  line_weight
order by 
  fish_name,
  line_weight
```

Oracle databases provide built in functions like rank() that can help you with this type of query if a group by doesn't help.  For example, if you want to see the highest weight of the fish for each grouping of fish and line weight, you could write a query with rank() as follows (this is probably not necessary in this situation):

```
select 
  fish_name,
  line_weight,
  fish_weight max_fish_weight
from (
select
  fish_name,
  line_weight,
  fish_weight,
  rank() over (partition by fish_name, line_weight order by fish_weight desc) r
from
  <your table name>
) 
where r = 1
order by 
  fish_name, 
  line_weight
```